# Por que o id do sequelize auto-incrementa mesmo sem ter adicionado os dados?

Tags: javascript, mysql, banco-de-dados, node.js, sequelize-js

Olá,  tenho uma tabela que possui[id, user, password, level]  seguindo essas configurações:

```
 id: {
   type:sequelize.INTEGER,
   primaryKey: true,
   autoIncrement: true,
   allowNull: false
 },
 user: {
   type: sequelize.STRING,
   allowNull: false,
   unique: true
 },
 password: {
   type: sequelize.TEXT,
   allowNull: false

 },
 level: {
   type: sequelize.STRING,
   allowNull: false
 }
})
```

sempre que tento criar um novo usuário e ele já existe, retorna o erro "SequelizeUniqueConstraintError" , até ai tudo ok, pois eu tinha configurado isso, como mostra o código a cima. Entrentanto, quando eu crio um novo usuário sem retornar esse erro, o  "id" do novo usuário , no banco de dados, aparece como se a tentativa anterior tivesse dado certo, exemplo:

-dei vários cliques na criação de um novo usuário com o mesmo nome e retornou vários erros, todavia, após conseguir criar um novo com  êxito, o id estava nessa numeração.

```
13  william1    william15   admin
14  william william15   admin
34  willia  william15   admin
59  will    william15   admin
```

Código de criação de um novo usuário:

```
rCreateUser.post('/', async (req: Request, res:Response)=> {
  const {user, password, level} = req.body
  try{
    const creatingUser: Model<any, any> = await Credencial_model.create({
      user:user,
      password:password,
      level: level
    })
    
    return res.json(creatingUser)
  }catch( Err) {
    console.log(Err.name)
    if(Err.name === 'SequelizeUniqueConstraintError'){
      res.status(409).json({info:'usuario já existe', error:true})
    }
  }
})
```

Comment: Esse é o comportamento normal do Sequelize, ou talvez do próprio banco de dados. Se você não quiser este comportamento, o correto seria você fazer um `if` para verificar se o `user` já existe e lançar o erro ou retornar um _status_. Uma alternativa seria usar [_Transactions_](https://sequelize.org/master/manual/transactions.html), mas acho que seria exagero para o seu caso.

Comment: Certo, eu pensei na alternativa do IF e irei implementá-la. Meu objetivo mesmo era saber se isso é um bug ou algo do tipo,aparentemente não, simplemente, achei que o próprio sequelize faria uma validação para mim. Desse modo, agradeço pela sua respota.